# Minimising object by sliding left/right while maximising another object onto the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, screen

What class/properties/method should I use when I want to create a screen that causes object to move away from screen while minimising when I swipe my fingers left or right, which will bring up a new object onto the screen maximising it.
Like when you're choosing a music and you're swiping left and right, the disc minimises to the left/right while another disc maximises from the left/right.

An example of this would be the Angry bird star wars level selection page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is awfully vague, and it sounds like you're asking how to create an original animation.

I **think** you are asking for a time machine like effect, where there are a stack of tiles that fade off into the distance.

Take a look at the iCarousel framework, available on github, and written by Nick Lockwood. It has lots of different ways of presenting groups of tiles, including a time machine look.

Take a look at this image: [image]

Comment: I cannot verbalise my though that's why its so vague. I was asking what class I need to use, is it UIPageViewController or something else

Comment: If you can't articulate your thoughts then we can't help you. I **think** what you are describing is a time machine affect. Like I said, take a look at the [**iCarousel framework**](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) on github (link). In that repository are a number of demo projects. Take a look at the one called "iOS Demo".  There is a button in that demo that lets you change the type of carousel. Try the "Time Machine" option.